# OpenPyXL - updating my code to iter_rows()

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working with a huge Excel file with 15 000+ rows & 20 columns. I tried changing it with OpenPyXl with this:

```
for row in range(2,864):
copysource = ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value
sportsource = ws.cell(row=i, column=2).value
catsource = ws.cell(row=i, column=3).value #...
```

but my memory got killed by the vastness of this beast I guess. I'm trying to update my code with iter_rows(), but I don't quite get shifting into other columns yet. Here's what I have so far:

```
for reg_row in reg.iter_rows("A2:A864"):
    for reg_cell in reg_row:
        copysource = reg_cell.value  #
```

Thank you very much!
g

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but if you wish to edit an existing file then you will need to load all of it into memory. `iter_rows` only avoids keeping rows in memory but the cells are there.

Comment: I decided to switch my .xls file to .csv & my problems disappeared. Way easier to read too. Thank you very much for your help anyway. :)

Comment: Great if you can avoid xlsx altogether but I don't think you can manipulate CSV in place, either.